# What's a benefit of empty interface over a class property?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, you can indicate that an Event listener should be queued by implementing a `ShouldQueue` interface, which has no method in it (more on it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#queued-event-listeners)). It's also used in a few different places throughout a framework (e.g. in Jobs).

Does it give you some particular benefits compared to using static class properties?

I am taking an EdX course on [Software Construction](https://www.edx.org/course/software-construction-data-abstraction-ubcx-softconst1x), and TA there claims that (at least in Java) empty interfaces are something that should not be used. Is it different in PHP?

Comment: Interfaces are easier to test and (unlike properties) they can be used for type-hinting.

Comment: Could you give me some specific examples of situations where you'd want to type-hint based on an empty interface in Laravel, and how it would help in testing?

Comment: I don't do Laravel (too much globals for my liking) so I can't advise. The type-hinting is the cardinal difference between a property and an interface, whether it makes sense to be used depends on the case at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take your example of `ShouldQueue` this interface can be implemented to indicate in the that a `command|event|notification|anything` should be pushed to a queue.

We can follow this through to see where this interface is utilised in the command example, and we get to the `Dispatcher`

```
protected function commandShouldBeQueued($command)
{
    return $command instanceof ShouldQueue;
}

// Which is called in the dispatch method

public function dispatch($command)
{
    if ($this->queueResolver && $this->commandShouldBeQueued($command)) {
        return $this->dispatchToQueue($command);
    }

    return $this->dispatchNow($command);
}
```

So it follows that simply by implementing this empty interface, we can change the behaviour of the how the command is dispatched. The Framework then, I would say, uses the interface as an indication of intended behaviours.

I think you can determine that this is clearer than a class constant, because you don't really care which classes implement the interface, just understand that by doing so you're agreeing to a behaviour being possible, even if the specifics of that behaviour aren't mandated by the interface's contract.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) 3+ years after asking this I think it was not the best question, since it's quite opinion based. If I were to answer my question right now, I'd say there are no benefits to using empty interfaces, it's just a design decision. We could be checking if some class constant was defined for example. Or Jobs could have a static method shouldQueue determining whether to queue them or not. Using an empty interface is just one of many possible ways to achieve the same goal, we're still asking a class instance whether it should be queued or not.